# Resources to find overseas volunteer opportunities with technical skills?

Tags: planning, online-resources, international-travel, volunteering

I'm a software engineer, and I want to volunteer my abilities in a foreign country for a month or two, preferably for a charitable organization. I previously did some work for the Grameen Foundation in Ghana, which I very much enjoyed, but haven't been able to find any resources to plan my next trip.

I've seen the questions *[Volunteering opportunities when travelling overseas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1899/volunteering-opportunities-when-travelling-overseas)* and *[Website resources for 'out there' jobs related to travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/website-resources-for-out-there-jobs-related-to-travel)*. However, I'm not looking to get paid, and I'm not looking to "tour" as I volunteer in the country.

Are there any websites where I can get access to these types of opportunities?

Comment: [Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink) (applies also to "this")

Comment: Might have to do some clever search filtering, but http://WorkAway.info is another site with many opportunities, including non-profits and charities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not specifying where you are going. If known, it would make giving you pointers much easier. Also, two months for helping out as a software engineer is awfully short; by the time you can start getting something done, it's time to move on.

That said, here are two websites you might want to check out (spam filter prevents me from posting more):

- **OneWorld** ("global justice online", "where the good guys gang up", "OneWorld brings the latest jobs and volunteer positions from organisations working to create a better world.") Their site has a section titled "Ethical Jobs" with a subsection titled ["Volunteer Positions"](http://oneworldgroup.org/jobs).
- **idealist.org** lets you search for ["Volunteer Opportunities"](http://www.idealist.org/search/v2/?search_type=volop&search_browser_options_initial_sort=published_date) under "What Are You Looking For?".

For two more, search for devnetjobs and (vacatureblad dot org).

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what your technical skills are.  Telecoms geeks should beeline for [Télécoms Sans Frontières](http://www.tsfi.org/en) , while IT folks are spoiled for choice: Wikipedia has an [entire category listing them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aInformation_technology_charities).  Larger outfits like [Mercy Corps](http://www.mercycorps.org/) also have opportunities for IT people.

Comment: I don't work in Telecom. Separate from that though, it seems like the Wikipedia page you linked to either has charities that don't use volunteers or computer recycling programs for US/UK residents.

Comment: The "computer recycling" groups do generally need volunteers to install and maintain the equipment.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually going to suggest Bankers Without Borders by Grameen. Since you liked volunteering with that organization, why not go with them again to another country?